# Spark: Avoiding Namespace Conflict when building modified spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am building a custom spark into a jar file. And I want to use that while using the default spark build.

How do I change the namespace from `org.apache.spark.allOfSpark` into `org.another.spark.allOfSpark` without going through all files?

I want to do this in order to avoid conflict when importing modules. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using shade in sbt.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the build tool you are using, you could use Maven's [`relocation`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) feature to move your custom spark into a new package at build-time. There are similar features in sbt and other build tools.

If you specify what you are using to build your project, I can further help on your issue.

-- **UPDATE**

Here is a sample code for your `pom.xml` that should help you getting started :

```
<project>
  <!-- Your project definition here, with the groupId, artifactId, and it's dependencies --> 
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <relocations>
                <relocation>
                  <pattern>org.apache.spark</pattern>
                  <shadedPattern>shaded.org.apache.spark</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
              </relocations>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

This will effectively move all of Spark into a new package called `shaded.org.apache.spark` when you package your application (when you ask Maven to produce a jar).

If you need to exclude certain packages, you can use the `<exclude>` tag as shown in the link of Maven's relocation.

If what you are trying to achieve is simply to customize some parts of Spark, I would advise you to either fork [Spark's code](https://github.com/apache/spark) and directly rewrite parts of MLLib, and then build it only for you (or contribue it to the community if it can useful).

Or you could simply pull it as a dependency from Maven and just overwrite the classes you are modifying, Maven should then use your own class instead of the one in the original Spark package.

Comment: I am using sbt most of the time but I am currently trying to build using mvn.  My knowledge in both build tools is very minimal. I don't know how to modify the pom.xml and my only experience with writing build.sbt is just writing a few dependencies to a spark app. If you could point me to where I can insert the code for `relocation`, I would be very thankful. To be more specific, my modifications can all be found inside spark-mllib.

Comment: Just based on the link I gave you, you should be able to find easily what you need to add to your `pom.xml` file. I updated my answer with a snippet to give you an idea of how to do it, but I don't have the name of packages you are using. However, I am not so sure now of what you are trying to achieve. Are you looking to rewrite some parts of MLLib and to keep the rest of Spark as it is, or do you want a complete custom Spark ? I don't see in the latter case why you would want to keep a custom Spark and the original in the same project .

Comment: I am actually rewriting some parts of MLLib. I want to package MLLib into a jar file and use it inside spark-kernel in Jupyter using `%addJar` magic. The reason why I want to change the naming is that I want to avoid conflict when doing `import org.apache.spark.ml.something` by doing `import org.another.spark.ml.something`. I ultimately want to contribute back to the community but for now, I want to test whether my modifications are better.

Comment: Then you should try the relocation code I've put, this should solve your issue

Comment: I inserted your code inside the pom.xml of default spark-1.5.0. There are several relocations there so I just inserted `<relocation><pattern>org.apache.spark</pattern><shadedPattern>org.something.spark</shadedPattern></relocation>`. However, I am getting a lot of errors. Am I doing this right?

Comment: When you are packaging you are getting a lot of errors ? What type of errors ?

Comment: I think they are mostly from `org.apache.spark.network`. I'm building using `build/mvn -DskipTests clean package`, which works when I didn't make any changes in pom.xml.

Comment: What if you only used those patterns : `<relocation><pattern>org.apache.spark.ml</pattern><shadedPattern>org.something.spa‌​rk.ml</shadedPattern></relocation><relocation><pattern>org.apache.spark.mllib</pattern><shadedPattern>org.something.spa‌​rk.mllib</shadedPattern></relocation> ` ?